# Convert List To Comma Separated MySQL Insert Statements

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

I've the following two classes;

```
public class CarModels
{
    public List<Model> Model{ get; set; }

    public CarModels()
    {
        Model = new List<Model>();
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled{ get; set; }
}
```

How can I extract the data into the format like

(ModelId,Name,Enabled),(ModelId,Name,Enabled),(ModelId,Name,Enabled) etc

Comment: look up how to use `string.Join` method

Comment: Are you planning on writing your own data layer?

Comment: My advice to anyone planning to write a custom data layer: Don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.Join(",", models.Select(m => String.Format("({0},{1},{2})", m.ModelId, m.Name, m.Enabled)));
```

That will give you string with `False` and `True` as Enabled values. If you want `Enabled` and `Disabled` instead, then use: `m.Enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled"` when formatting model string.

---

Full sample (with NBuilder used to create sample models):

```
IEnumerable<Model> models = Builder<Model>.CreateListOfSize(3).Build();
Func<Model, string> formatModel = 
    m => String.Format("({0},{1},{2})", m.ModelId, m.Name, m.Enabled);
string result = String.Join(",", models.Select(formatModel));
```

Output:

> (1,Name1,False),(2,Name2,True),(3,Name3,False)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var models = carModels.Model.Aggregate<Model, string>("", (s, m) =>
{
    return s + String.Format(",({0},{1},{2})", m.ModelId, m.Name, m.Enabled);
}).Substring(1);
```